# Breadcrumb microdata help

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs, microdata

I'm trying to help Google generate appropriate breadcrumb details for my website. I am currently using this as the breadcrumb:

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
<span class="crust" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://www.radonsystems.net" class="crumb" rel="up" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Home</span>
    </a>
    <span class="arrow">
        <span>&raquo;</span>
    </span>
</span>
<span class="crust" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://www.radonsystems.net/business/profile.2" class="crumb" rel="up" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Business Profile</span>
    </a>
</span>
</div>
```

However, this isn't helping Google at all, even the testing tool does not generate the breadrumb link, though it does see the microdata and correctly identifies it as breadcrumb microdata.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to add a new column, in which numbers could be entered as format: 1,3,4. Then, I retrieved it from the database, exploded it into an array, and for each number, I'd retrieve information about that link id: url, text, then output it.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the microdata schemas at data-vocabulary.org, I would use the newer ones at http://schema.org which is the joint project by Google, Yahoo and Microsoft. It has a wider range of schemas to be more expressive with your data modeling.

In particular, the `webpage` schema is what you want for defined breadcrumb microdata.
http://www.schema.org/WebPage

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list your pages, you need to create a version that contains enough substance that should be sought.