# Marking the last breadcrumb item in Microdata

Tags: html, breadcrumbs, microdata, rdfa, structured-data

for the following code:

```
<nav id="breadcrumbs-as-title" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#" >
  <ul class="f1 my-levels-2" itemprop="breadcrumb" >
     <li typeof="v:Breadcrumb" ><a href="url1.html" title="title 1" rel="v:url" property="v:title" >title 1</a></li>
     <li typeof="v:Breadcrumb" ><a href="url2.html" title="title 2" rel="v:url" property="v:title" >title 2</a></li>
     <li typeof="v:Breadcrumb" ><strong><span property="v:title" >title 3 (= the title of the current page)</span></strong></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I see the following error:

> @type: Breadcrumb
>   title: title 3
>   url: A value for the url field is required.

because my last `<li>` has no URL.

Should I mark the last `<li>` as breadcrumb? or remove the mark, as the code in - [Breadcrumb microdata help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057571/breadcrumb-microdata-help/30747341#30747341)

Should I add 'dummy' item as suggested in [How to markup the last non linking item in breadcrumbs list using JSON-LD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688608/how-to-markup-the-last-non-linking-item-in-breadcrumbs-list-using-json-ld/33689086#33689086) ?

Answer (score 2):

Your example uses mostly RDFa properties (`typeof`, `property`, …), and one Microdata property (`itemprop`). Unless there is more Microdata not shown in this example, it doesn’t really make sense to mix these two syntaxes like that.

Furthermore, you are using the vocabulary Data-Vocabulary.org, which is no longer maintained. You didn’t state if you have a specific use case in mind, but it’s likely that you want to use the vocabulary [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) (it’s [the only vocabulary supported by Google](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35134834/1591669), according to their documenation).

In Schema.org, you would use the type [`BreadcrumbList`](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList). You can use Microdata, RDFa, or JSON-LD. See the example at the bottom of the page.

As mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691751/1591669) to the question you linked to, Schema.org says that the breadcrumbs are "typically ending with the current page", and Google says for their breadcrumb-related feature that it "may include or omit a breadcrumb for the page on which it appears".

In case you do provide the last item, but you don’t want to link it, you can provide a hidden URL (with the `link` element in RDFa/Microdata),